# Java 2 API's caused: Duplicate files copied in APK

Tags: java, android, api, android-gradle-plugin

So, my problem is a conflict between joda-time and JavaMail API.

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt

File1: C:\Users\sdilab\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\
       joda-time\joda-time\2.4\89e9725439adffbbd41c5f5c215c136082b34a7f\
       joda-time-2.4.jar

File2: C:\Users\sdilab\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
       files-2.1\com.sun.mail\android-mail\1.5.5\
       53a2f927b235acb565dbe9314ececfb7e6d43020\android-mail-1.5.5.jar
```

The log above says that I've two files with the same name and those files come from API.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Exclude META-INF/LICENSE.txt `android { packagingOptions { exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' } }`

Comment: Want to answer the question? You solved the problem.

Comment: great, i'have posted the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude META-INF/LICENSE.txt file. In your `build.gradle`:

```
android { 
  //more things
  packagingOptions { 
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' 
    //more things
  } 
}
```